# cross compile protobuf files in cmake with Yocto sdk

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers, yocto

I am trying to compile [cartographer](https://github.com/googlecartographer/cartographer/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) in a Docker container with an SDK generated with Yocto.

The SDK is running well since I can cross compile what I want on it, except cartographer.

The issue I have is the CMakeLists.txt calls `protoc`( from [protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf)). I have protoc installed in the host and target directory.

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${DIR}/${FIL_WE}.pb.cc"
         "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${DIR}/${FIL_WE}.pb.h"
  COMMAND  ${PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE}
  ARGS --cpp_out  ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} -I
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} ${ABS_FIL}
  DEPENDS ${ABS_FIL}
  COMMENT "Running C++ protocol buffer compiler on ${ABS_FIL}"
  VERBATIM
)
```

I'm a bit confused because while having protoc already available, I'm calling protoc with an x86_64 architecture while I am using an `aarch64-poky-linux-` compiler. This leads to libraries not found, since architectures are somehow mixed up. glog is also installed on both architectures:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/yocto/yocto_topdir/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi-cm3-64/usr/lib/libglog.so', needed by 'cartographer/kalman_filter/kalman_filter_unscented_kalman_filter_test'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/yocto/yocto_topdir/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi-cm3-64/usr/lib/libglog.so', needed by 'cartographer/kalman_filter/kalman_filter_gaussian_distribution_test'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/yocto/yocto_topdir/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi-cm3-64/usr/lib/libglog.so', needed by 'cartographer/common/common_fixed_ratio_sampler_test'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/yocto/yocto_topdir/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi-cm3-64/usr/lib/libglog.so', needed by 'cartographer/common/common_lua_parameter_dictionary_test'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/yocto/yocto_topdir/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi-cm3-64/usr/lib/libglog.so', needed by 'cartographer/common/common_blocking_queue_test'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/yocto/yocto_topdir/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi-cm3-64/usr/lib/libglog.so', needed by 'cartographer/mapping/mapping_probability_values_test'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/yocto/yocto_topdir/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi-cm3-64/usr/lib/libglog.so', needed by 'cartographer/common/common_math_test'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/yocto/yocto_topdir/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi-cm3-64/usr/lib/libglog.so', needed by 'cartographer/common/common_rate_timer_test'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/yocto/yocto_topdir/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi-cm3-64/usr/lib/libglog.so', needed by 'cartographer/mapping_2d/mapping_2d_probability_grid_test'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/yocto/yocto_topdir/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi-cm3-64/usr/lib/libglog.so', needed by 'cartographer/mapping/mapping_trajectory_connectivity_test'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/yocto/yocto_topdir/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi-cm3-64/usr/lib/libglog.so', needed by 'cartographer/mapping/mapping_submaps_test'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/yocto/yocto_topdir/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi-cm3-64/usr/lib/libglog.so', needed by 'cartographer/kalman_filter/kalman_filter_pose_tracker_test'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

One strange thing is the mentioned directory (/home/yocto/yocto_topdir/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi-cm3-64) only exists in the Yocto workspace when generating the SDK. It is not a CMAKE variable from what I checked but it comes from somewhere else.

Simply doing in my container solved the issue

```
mkdir -p /home/yocto/yocto_topdir/tmp/sysroots
ln -s /usr/local/oecore-sdk/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux /home/yocto/yocto_topdir/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi-cm3-64
```

I don't write it as an answer since it's a 'hack'. It simply points to the folder container the sysroot of the target

EDIT: Added more details

Comment: As far as I understand: you need **host** (x86_64) protobuf **executable**, because you run it during the *build*. But you need **target** (aarch64) protobuf **libraries**, because they are used on *runtime*, and **target** protobuf **includes**, because they should be *compatible* with libraries. In your toolchain file set variable [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM.html) to *ONLY* or *BOTH*, so CMake would find executables on host. Other variables *CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_..* set to *NEVER*.

Comment: I added some details. I checked and it is already done. I know since it compiles with the symbolic link I added during the EDIT